# File upload to a specific folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attachment-fu

- I am using attachment_fu for file uploading... it saves the files to asset/0000/0001... something like this... i want to upload a file to a specific folder defined by a user... for example images to a specific folder... just like galleries...
- how will i achieve this... help me out here...

thankx

take care..

Answer (score 1):

After the upload is done, move the file to the correct position.